# How do i use Get-clipboard output in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to use text that is inside the clipboard inside a powershell script. So what the purpose for the script, i want to be able to copy a file directory and then run the script so it uses the copied directory as a automatic destination. So my idea was to do something like this:

`Copy-Item C:\Users\gif.gif -Destination "Copied Directory"`

I'm very new to powershell scripting, so an explenation of what is going on would be nice but not needed. I origionlly thought that this could work but nope XD, this should have been a simple project but yeah it wasn't meant to be easy.

`Copy-Item C:\Users\J.J\Documents\TouchPortal/Make_30fps_gif.bat -Destination | Get-Clipboard`

Would love to get some help with this, and thank you in advance!

Comment: `$test = get-clipboard; Copy-Item C:\Users\J.J\Documents\TouchPortal/Make_30fps_gif.bat -Destination $test`? Your attempt is not how piping works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell core including versions 6 & 7 `Get-Clipboard` only works with text.  If you use it after copying a folder it will return null.

In PowerShell 5.1 (Windows PowerShell) you can use the `-Format` parameter with `Get-Clipboard`

See [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62377454/4749264) for a better description and example using `-Format`.

If you need to use the newer versions, you can use the shift + context menu choice > Copy as Path to get the folder's string path on to the clipboard, but that will quote the path.  The quoted path will then be rejected by `Copy-Item`.

However, you could quickly replace the quotes like below.

```
Copy-Item 'C:\temp\BaseFile.txt' -Destination (Get-Clipboard).Replace('"',"")
```

Caution though, this seems hazardous, and I wouldn't advise it.  I use `Get-Clipboard` all the time to get data into a console session and can attest that it's too easy to make mistakes.  The clipboard is so transient, and it's use so ubiquitous that even if you make this work it's bound to burn you at some point.

Maybe you can elaborate on what you're trying to do and why.  Then we can brainstorm the best approach.

Comment: Good answer, but note that Windows PowerShell _does_ allow you to retrieve data other than text, including files and directories, namely via the `-Format` parameter. Unfortunately, that is no longer supported in PowerShell [Core].

Comment: thank you that is perfect! also thank you for explaning.
so what i'm trying to do is this; i have the program Imagemagick that can convert a png sequence with one line of code if i have the folder where to png sequence is located. i used to do this with commend prompt by first setting the directory and then this line of code: `convert *.png -delay 1x30 -loop 0 gif.gif`. then i did the same with moving a batch file with this code. But i just thought of doing it entirely with powershell by using cmd. but i wouldn't know how to implement that with the directory yet.

Comment: Ok, i blew myself away, so i have been using powershell for just 3 hours or so and i think this is the simplest way of doing what i wanted. apperently imagemagick also works with powershell as a input so that made everything a lot easier. 
`cd (Get-Clipboard).Replace('"',"")
    convert *.png -delay 1x30 -loop 0 gif.gif`
now combined with a program that can run powershell script (touch portal, amazing program especially for programmers) it makes things incredebly easy!

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Steven's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62376711/45375):

- In *Windows PowerShell* only, you can use [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Clipboard?view=powershell-5.1)'s `-Format` parameter to request clipboard data *other* than text.
- In *PowerShell [Core, v6+]*, this is no longer supported, and *text* is indeed the only data type supported by `Get-Clipboard`.

---

In *Windows PowerShell*, if you've used File Explorer to copy a directory to the clipboard (using the regular `Copy` shortcut-menu command or the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> keyboard shortcut), you can access it as [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance by passing `-Format FileDropList` to `Get-Clipboard`.

- Note: `-Format FileDropList` returns a *collection* of file-system-info objects, so as to also support *multiple* files/directories having been copied to the clipboard; thanks to [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), however, you can treat this collection like a single object - assuming truly only *one* file or directory was copied.

```sh
# Note: Windows PowerShell only.
# The .FullName property returns the full directory path.
Copy-Item C:\Users\gif.gif -Destination (Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList).FullName
```

In *PowerShell [Core, v6+]* you'll indeed have to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click method and select `Copy as path` from the shortcut menu, in order to ensure that a file/directory is copied as a (double-quoted, full) *path string*, as shown in Steven's answer.